# Understanding webp encoder options

Tags: encoding, image-compression, webp

I'm currently experimenting with webp encoder (**no wic**) on windows 64 environment. My samples are 10 jpg stock photos depicting landscapes and houses, and the photos already optimized in jpegtran. I do this because my goal is to optimize the images of a whole website where the images have already been compressed with photoshop using the save for web command with various values on quality and then optimized with jpegtran.

I found out that using values smaller than **-q 85** have a visual impact on the quality of the webp images. So I'm playing with values above **90** where the difference is smaller. I also concluded that I have to use **-jpeg_like** because without it the output is sometimes bigger in size than the original, which is not acceptable. I also use **-m 6 -f 100 -strong** because I really don't mind about the time the encoder needs to produce the output and trying to achieve the smoother results. I tried several values for these and concluded that **-m 6 -f 100 -strong** have the best output regarding quality and size.

I also tried the **-preset photo** avoiding any other parameter except -q but the size of the output gets bigger.

What I don't understand from https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/cwebp#options are the options **-sns** , **-segments** which seem to have a great impact on the output size. Sometimes the output  is bigger and sometimes smaller in size for the same options but I haven't concluded yet what is the reason for that and how to properly use them.

I also don't understand the **-sharpness** option which doesn't have an impact at the output size at least for me.

My approach is far less than a scientific approach and more like a trial and error method and If anybody knows how to use those options for the specific input and explain them for optimum results I would appreciate such a feedback.

Answer (score 1):

-strong and -sharpness only change the strength of the filtering in the *header* of the compressed bitstream. They will be used at decoding time. That's why you don't see a change in file size for these.

-sns controls the choice of filtering strength and quantization values within each segments. A segment is just a group of macroblocks in the picture, that are believed to be sharing similar properties regarding complexity and compressibility. A complex photo should likely use the maximum allowed 4 segments (which is the default).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I finally understand how -sns & -segments work and because they are very difficult to be generalized on a large set of images I left those two out from my function. From the documentation I also noticed that the default value for -segments (4) has no effect unless -low_memory is used. So does this mean by default that we should use -low_memory? And I still don't understand the sharpness. What does the sharpness mean for the decoding process and decoding time. Will it take more or less decoding time or is it anything else? Will it be noticeable from the end user?